# Getting the value of Full-Row Clickable Gridview and Display in Textbox

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that loads data from a stored procedure.

**OBJECTIVE:**

1. to make the full gridview row clickable by hiding the select column in the gridview - I was able to do this by doing the code below in the RowDataBound event.
2. Next is when I click a full row in the gridview, I should be able to get the data / values from the row selected and display this in the textboxes in the modal pop up to appear. This is for UPDATING / EDITING FUNCTIONS.

Here's what I have got

```
 protected void grdTenant_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Style["display"] = "none";

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        { 

            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] =
                "javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);";
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] =
                "javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);";
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] =
            Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink
                (this.grdTenant, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("javascript:$find('{0}').show();",ModalEditTenant.ClientID ));

//this line does not work in retrieving row data
   IDataRecord dataRow = (IDataRecord)e.Row.DataItem;
        txtRPCode.Text = Convert.ToString(dataRow["Retail Partner"]);

        }
    }
```

As an alternative, I do this to achieve the second goal but fails to do the first

```
  protected void grdTenant_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = grdTenant.SelectedRow;
        txtRPCode.Text  = row.Cells[1].Text;

        ModalEditTenant.Show();
    }
```

But, this method works only when the select button column is visible and when  it is clicked, it fails to do so when the full row is selected.

How can I make the full row select and retrieves the data to textbox successfully (with the select column hidden)

---

This is how gridview bind the data from the stored procedure datasource.

```
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            //DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTenantList", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", ddlSelectLoc.SelectedValue );


            try
            {
                con.Open();
                grdTenant.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
                grdTenant.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                grdTenant.DataBind();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: Can you please add "gridviewid.datasource" binding code in your question??

Comment: Not a .aspx file code, I need C# code where you binding data into the gridview. Ex. grdTenant.DataSource = XYZ; grdTenant.DataBinding();...etc Are you using datatable to bind your grid?

Comment: I have updated it again, as Ive said earlier I am using a stored procedure to load some data in the gridview, In my dropdown list, when a user select an item, the gridview will automatically load data based on the selection

Comment: Don't use `try {} catch(Exception ex){throw ex;}`. All it does is mess up the stack trace to make it look like the exception came from the point of the `throw`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FindControl()`method.

Instead of `txtRetailPartner` place your `TextBox ID`.

```
txtRPCode.Text = ((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtRetailPartner")).Text;
```

Comment: i have this error, after doing that - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: what is your TextBox Name? did you replace that in the above line and try?

Comment: yes, i replace txtRetailPartner to the name of actual textbox which is txtRPCode.

Comment: txtRPCode is inside the gridview? which value you are trying to get from gridview to textbox?

Comment: no, no boundfield defined or template field inside a gridview sir.

Answer (score 1):

Use my logic below in `RowDataBound` event to get `DataItem`:

```
protected void grdTenant_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Style["display"] = "none";

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    { 
         IDataRecord dataRow = (IDataRecord)e.Row.DataItem;
         txtRPCode.Text = Convert.ToString(dataRow["Retail Partner Code"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I include your code after the onclick part in my code, and it give me this error: Error 3 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Yes it is inside the popup

Comment: Which GridView Column data, do you want to show in txtRPCode Textbox? Can you please give me  index of the column like 1st Column, 2nd Column,...etc???

Comment: actually all of the column in the gridview is tasked to be moved or shown in the modal pop up since they are for updating / editing fucntion, just to make the question simpler, I have given the first column in the gridview which is the Retail Partner Code (Name of the column as per stored proc) and that to be delivered in the txtRPCode textbox in the modal pop up extender. In the current case, Item is not being accepted am i missing an assembly or namespace?

Comment: txtRPCode is the first column to be specific and to answer your question.

Comment: Hi Ricky, I resolved above ITEM error and updated my answer. Please replace e.Item.DataItem with e.Row.DataItem.

Comment: Hi @Dexterity, still does not work. The objective of opening the modal pop and putting the data from selected gridview row to the textboxes is not achieved. Thanks though for trying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75462/discussion-between-dexterity-and-rickyprogrammer).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer based on what is to achieved. Using my current codes posted as question , Just remove the one line code there and it will work

protected void grdTenant_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Style["display"] = "none";

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    { 

        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] =
            "javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);";
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] =
            "javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);";
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] =
        Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink
            (this.grdTenant, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);        
    }
}
```

**This line is removed:**

//This is no longer needed as it will make the onselectedindexchanged event ineffective as this will be run first.

**e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("javascript:$find('{0}').show();",ModalEditTenant.ClientID ));**

```
protected void grdTenant_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = grdTenant.SelectedRow;
        txtRPCode.Text  = row.Cells[1].Text;

        ModalEditTenant.Show();
    }
```

And everything will work as expected.